# What type of null/undefined is inferred?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

environment:

```
VS Code Version: 1.47.3
tsc Version: 4.0.0-dev.20200727
tsconfig.js: "strict": true,
```

code:

```
let x = null; // x is any type
let y = x; // x is null type(why? x is any type on top), y is null type

x = 1; // x is any type
y = 1; // error, y is null type
```

Is that normal? What type of x is inferred? I am confused

Comment: You will get more reasonable behavior with strict mode on. It is a bit weird, but it helps sometimes to be more loose to allow variables to be initialized with null/undefined before giving it its 'real' value. strictNullChecks on will solve this though and it's highly recommended.

Comment: it's in strict mode.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11263) which introduces control flow analysis (CFA) for variables implicitly typed as `any`

> In the example above, x and y implicitly have declared types of `any` but control flow analysis can determine their actual types at every reference. Therefore, no errors are reported even when the example is compiled with `--noImplicitAny`.

This analysis only kicks in for

> [...] `let` and `var` variables that have no type annotation and either no initial value or an initial value of **`null` or `undefined`**.

So let's see what happens in your example:

```
// x is implicitly any, with null assigned, so this new CFA analysis kicks in 
let x = null; 
// for x, based on the assignment on the previous line, x is known to be null
// y typed based on the type of x, so y has type null. 
// No special CFA is triggered for y since it is not assigned the null literal value
let y = x; 

// x can be assigned any type, since it has no type annotation, so number is fine
x = 1;

// y was actually given a type when it was declared, the null type, so you can't assign number
y = 1;

// x is now number based on previous assignments
x.toExponential()
```

When `x` is the target of an assignment, it behaves as `any`, allowing any type to be assigned to it. When it is used in an expression, it's type will be determined based on previous assignments.